# web service json mssql kendo ui connection... how to

Tags: json, sql-server-2008, service, kendo-ui

Im new at web programming and I have to make a website which will get the data from a mssql server. The thing I tried is just write SQL commands and get the data but I need to change the settings of internet explorer so it did not work. Now I want to write a web service to get the data form my server and formats the data like .json and then I need to use that service to display my list on my website. What is your suggestion where should I begin to work ? And Im using KendoUI for my website.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and probably most used approach nowadays is to use an ORM - most common EntityFramework for .NET developers, then in your web service you just return the objects and they are automatically serialized. 
Search the web for some tutorials.